# Can't launch chrome driver in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was always able to launch chromedriver server locally but then I tried to do this remotely and since then I am unable to launch it. I reinstalled chrome as well the chrome driver but nothing seems to fix this. Even when I give the path of my driver it won't launch.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Safari;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

namespace TestWebDriver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\laurens.putseys\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestWebDriver\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.2.21.0.0\driver\");
            driver.Url = "http://google.be";
            Console.ReadLine();
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: unknown error: chrome failed to start

  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

It started after I tried this:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver",@"/path/to/where/you/ve/put/chromedriver.exe"
```

Now I cannot launch the local either. Launching IE and Firefox local work without any problems. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you providing the location of chromedriver ?

Comment: Yes, I gave the absolute path to make sure it was correct.

Comment: can you post your code how you r initialising driver

Comment: The code is in the post, but there I didn't give the path in the constructor.

Comment: can you post full code, what r u trying to do?? also can you manually try to start chromedriver

Comment: I edited my post. It's a test project so not much is going on.

Comment: Maybe good to know is that I can launch firfox and IE local.

Comment: Hi all i managed to solve the problem! The problem was that Selenium looked in the wrong directory. There was an old instance of chrome so I deleted this in the appData folder. Thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: @John have you managed to get this working recently, with the latest Selenium, ChromeDriver etc?

Answer (score 1):

try downloading the driver and give its path to contractor - [LINK](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/)

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_PATH);
```

Answer (score 0):

By the version number (`2.21.371459`) you can tell that the ChromeDriver executable has been launched by your remote Selenium server. But the ChromeDriver was obviously unable to launch the Chrome browser. Is it installed on the server? Can you launch is manually? Can you watch the remote server on a screen and see what happens? Are there any error message boxes displayed by Chrome?

Maybe uninstalling and re-installing Chrome could help!

Comment: Hi yes I reinstalled chrome but it the error still remains. But I also cannot launch the local web driver now?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had the browser set to always run under the administrator.
So I started Visual Studio as an administrator and the problem was solved.