# Headless chrome not working as advertised

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome-headless

Having used this page as a reference:
http://executeautomation.com/blog/running-chrome-in-headless-mode-with-selenium-c/

I have tried to get Chrome working in headless mode (with a view to running under SpecFlow/xUnit). This has failed spectacularly and I would like to know if anyone has a solution/fix.

I'm running VS 2015 on Windows 7 with a .NET 4.7 console application and Google Chrome Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)...

Here's my packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.11.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.11.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="2.36.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.analyzers" version="0.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```

And here's my Class1.cs:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using Xunit;

namespace xUnitSpecFlowChrome
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void GoTest()
        {
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--headless");
            options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
            var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.daringfireball.net");
            var title = driver.Title;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what I see, when running that test, in the output:

```
------ Run test started ------
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.5727852]   Starting:    xUnitSpecFlowChrome
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3212989]     xUnitSpecFlowChrome.Class1.GoTest [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3239354]       System.InvalidOperationException : session not created exception
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=65.0.3325.162)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (SessionNotCreated)
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3264983]       Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3276332]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3280606]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3284914]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3289079]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3292786]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3296566]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3300055]         C:\git\xUnitSpecFlowChrome\xUnitSpecFlowChrome\Class1.cs(14,0): at xUnitSpecFlowChrome.Class1.GoTest()
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.3573096]   Finished:    xUnitSpecFlowChrome
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:04.757) ==========
```

**UPDATE**

Having changed nothing of apparent consequence, I am now seeing this in the output pane:

```
 ------ Run test started ------
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.3376673]   Starting:    xUnitSpecFlowChrome
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.8905380]     xUnitSpecFlowChrome.Class1.GoTest [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9024429]       OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:23698/session timed out after 60 seconds.
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9038433]       ---- System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9185440]       Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9199720]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9212636]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9224907]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9237665]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9250241]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9262697]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9275900]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9289251]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9302787]         C:\git\xUnitSpecFlowChrome\xUnitSpecFlowChrome\Class1.cs(16,0): at xUnitSpecFlowChrome.Class1.GoTest()
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9315103]         ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9327543]            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9339867]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.9698773]   Finished:    xUnitSpecFlowChrome
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:01:01.085) ==========
```

Comment: Referring to the following post, I am also running VS under local admin privs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985964/cant-launch-chrome-driver-in-selenium

Comment: According to this file my browser version is supported by my webdriver version: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt

Comment: Can you debug the error `NUnit couldn't find any tests in C:\git\xUnitSpecFlowChrome\xUnitSpecFlowChrome\bin\Debug\xUnitSpecFlowChrome.dll`?

Comment: My apologies - I may have made a typo. NUnit is not involved in this solution. Running the project now does not produce that error.

Comment: So is your question solved now or you are still looking out for an Answer?

Comment: Still looking for an answer. The issue being concerned with the failure reported by chromedriver: session not created exception
from tab crashed

Comment: Try adding a `--verbose` to the options, it might help you diagnose the problem. Have you set a binary location to chromedriver.exe, if needed?

Comment: I will try adding verbose. I did try specifying the binary location, but as I'm using a NuGet package the path it appeared to be using was no different than the one I provided.

Comment: I too have the same issue, if I remove options.AddArgument("--headless"); then it's working fine and fast if I keep  headless option then getting the timeout issue

Comment: @velmurugan See the chosen answer.

Comment: I too have that option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genuinely can't believe this was it:

```
options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
```

As accidentally found in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39299877/71376

Don't know why this option isn't documented or flagged up more - but I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

The error **System.InvalidOperationException : session not created exception** indicates that a session could not be created.

To configure **Headless Chrome** you have to pass the following arguments through an instance of **ChromeOptions** :

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--headless");
options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

### Additional Considertations

Ensure the following :

- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of Chrome.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Update

As you are still seeing the error as **from tab crashed**, this issue relates to **lack of memory** within the system/docker_image. You can find a detailed discussion in [**UnknownError: session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed**](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/20)

Comment: Cleaned solution and OS, as advised. Base Chrome is version as described in my post. The output persists as described above.

Comment: Ahhhh, can you check your system memory usage, `tab crashed` generally rises out of lack of memory space.

Comment: Retried after closing everything except VS. Max usage of memory was 41%. This is a 16GB machine.

Comment: I'm not using Docker, however, the message has now changed. I do not know why but I have posted it below the original post.

Comment: To be sure that I had not introduced an anomaly, I rebooted and started VS in admin mode immediately. Cleaned, rebuilt and ran the single test in the project and I got the original error output.

Comment: Should I be using Chromium or regular Chrome? I have the regularly installed vanilla Chrome.

Comment: @MattW Better to stick with regular Chrome. I was wondering in your code you mentioned about `using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;` but why not `using OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver;`

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver is not a namespace available to me - the code simply won't build. Should I modify the package list?

Comment: Can't find the OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver class in the documentation: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/

Comment: Using CCleaner sounds like a joke, how should this ever run on a pipeline? Seriously, this is not how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The posted answers did not work for me - the test works in Chrome, but not with the `--headless` option argument. However, it did not work as expected and I got a timeout error.

This code worked with the latest version... Window size is important for headless mode. Default sizes are `1280x800` for headed mode and `1366x768` in headless mode.

```
public void GoTest()
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
    options.AddArgument("--proxy-server='direct://'");
    options.AddArgument("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
    options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
    options.AddArgument("--headless");
    options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

    var _driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
    object html = _driver.ExecuteScript("return document.body.parentElement.outerHTML");

    _driver.Close();
}
```